# Is there a cv2 function/algorithm to track a cameras movements?

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv

I am trying to make a little piece of code that requires me to know the position of my camera. The problem is I need a way to estimate the camera's orientation and position from the perspective of the camera. Is there any openCV/other library that has a function that can do this? If not, what algorithm do I need to implement here to achieve this?

Comment: Look at visual odometry, egomotion, SLAM topics. These are complex topics. There are typically implemented in commercial softwares for Augmented Reality like Apple or Vuforia, or for autonomous driving, drone visual system.